# Conditional fill color setting of a single bar in a horizontal bar chart in D3.js v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a web questionnaire (list of mostly multiple choice but also other types of items).
After submitting the questionnaire i want to show a page comparing the choices of the respondent that has just filled in the questionnaire 
with choices made by all respondents up until then (totals).

I want to show the multiple choice items in horizontal bar charts (bars go from left to right).

I looked at:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386

There would off course be a description on the left of each alternative (multiple choice).

First of all the bar chart should reflect the total number of choices made for each alternative in the multiple choice question up until then.
Item 1 was chosen 3 times, item 2 was chosen 33 times etc.
The alternative chosen by the respondent who has just filled in the questionnaire should be given a sepperate bar color (fill color?).
This would allow him/her to compare their own choices with everyone who has done the questionnaire up until then.

I suppose it would be a conditional fill color setting of a single bar in a bar chart (persistent, not on MouseOver or something like that).

Can anyone point me to a horizontal bar chart that already has conditional fill color setting?
Would someone be so kind as to perhaps incorporate it into the Bostock bar chart? (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386)

This seems a useful addition to a bar chart that would be of benefit to many...

Help / suggestions would be appreciated.

I see the potential in D3.js but the learning curve can be steep indeed...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have to structure your data to not only pass numbers, but also a flag if it should be highlighted. Once you have it, you can either assign a class conditionally, or directly set the background or fill attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
  
  .chart div.highlighted {
  background-color: darkblue;
  }

</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [{
  value: 4,
  highlighted: false
},{
  value: 6,
  highlighted: false
},{
  value: 5,
  highlighted: true
},{
  value: 9,
  highlighted: false
}];

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) {return d.value;}))])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d.value) + "px"; })
   .classed('highlighted', function(d) { return d.highlighted; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Coderino, this is exactly what is was looking for, many thanks for your quick answer! :) This bar chart's source would be a JSON file(all respondents) and a Gravityforms questionaire (the respondent who will be compared to the responders in the JSON file before he is added to that file). Again many thanks.